# How to extract part of string in SQL before first of the repaeting characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, partial

I have in SQl rows with following mixed values.

```
322600;323800;325000;326200;327400;329200
0;0;0;0;0;0
1184168;1188182;1192196;1196210;1200224;1204238
0;0;0;0;0;0
0;0;0;0;0;0
```

I would need to obtain only values before the first semicolon i.e.

```
322600
0
1184168
0
0
```

I have tried:

```
,LEFT ([UtilizeProperties],CHARINDEX(';',[CalcTotGrossIncome])-1)
```

but I get only 3 first digits and

```
,SUBSTRING([UtilizeProperties],CHARINDEX(';',[UtilizeProperties])-1,LEN([UtilizeProperties])-CHARINDEX(';',[UtilizeProperties]))
```

make my first values to 0 and

```
,SUBSTRING([UtilizeProperties],CHARINDEX(';',[UtilizeProperties])+1,LEN([UtilizeProperties]))
```

takes them away totaly.

Thankful for kind advice.

I use SQL Service Management Studio

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is correct except you are using different columns in `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX`. Change like so:

```sql
LEFT(UtilizeProperties, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(';', UtilizeProperties), 0) - 1)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for prompt responses, yes LEFT(UtilizeProperties, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(';', UtilizeProperties), 0) - 1) has worked. :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query [CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

This function searches for one character expression inside a second character expression, returning the starting position of the first expression if found.

Syntax

```
CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind , expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
```

To get all the values you need to replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`. You can add `order by` clause in final query for sorting the values.

```
with cte (SampleData) as
(
select '322600;323800;325000;326200;327400;329200'
union
select '0;0;0;0;0;0'
union
select '1184168;1188182;1192196;1196210;1200224;1204238'
union
select '0;0;0;0;0;0'
union
select '0;0;0;0;0;0'
)
SELECT 
        CAST(LEFT(SampleData, CHARINDEX(';', SampleData)-1) AS INT) OutputValue
From cte
```

Here is the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=537b4cb3430f33b58f5fe21746438a09) demo.